# When updating on Ubuntu I get: Invalid 'Date' entry in Release

Tags: ubuntu, apt, ubuntu-16.04

When I do:

```
apt-get update -qq -y
```

I am getting this error:

```
W: Invalid 'Date' entry in Release file /var/lib/apt/lists/osquery-packages.s3.amazonaws.com_xenial_dists_xenial_Release
```

OS details:

> No LSB modules are available.
>
> Distributor ID:   Ubuntu
>
> Description:  Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
>
> Release:  16.04
>
> Codename: xenial

The instructions that I followed for osquery:

```
apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 1484120AC4E9F8A1A577AEEE97A80C63C9D8B80B
add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://osquery-packages.s3.amazonaws.com/xenial xenial main"

apt-get update -qq -y

apt-get install --no-install-recommends --no-install-suggests --force-yes -y -q \
osquery
```

**UPDATE:**

Did some tests. It's not related to this:

```
export TIMEZONE=UTC

cp /usr/share/zoneinfo/${TIMEZONE} /etc/localtime
echo "${TIMEZONE}" | tee /etc/timezone
dpkg-reconfigure --frontend noninteractive tzdata
```

**UPDATE 2**

Inside of `/var/lib/apt/lists/osquery-packages.s3.amazonaws.com_xenial_dists_xenial_Release`:

```
Origin: osquery-builder
Label: osquery-builder
Suite: xenial
Codename: xenial
Date: Fri, 10 Feb 2017 15:02:17 -0800
Components: main
Architectures: amd64
```

Comment: Did you look at the file?

Comment: Here is what I found for date: `Date: Fri, 10 Feb 2017 15:02:17 -0800` in `/var/lib/apt/lists/osquery-packages.s3.amazonaws.com_xenial_dists_xenial_Release`

Comment: I don't know how this stuff works. So it's hard for me to unknown if something is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A recent update to `apt` now requires that the `Date` in Release files be in UTC.

Your third party repository's Release file has a date which is not in UTC, hence the warning. [While apt will continue working](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+bug/1649086) with this file, it will simply pretend that the date was UTC, which could cause minor issues like updates not appearing for several hours.

The solution is to contact the third party repository maintainer and ask them to fix their repo.

Comment: It's Facebook... Not much I can do. I imagine they know about it.

Comment: Don't imagine they know about it. They probably don't. Otherwise they would have just fixed it...

Comment: I think they are just slow: https://github.com/facebook/osquery/issues/3000

Comment: Well, it looks like they've got the failing hard part down. Now they just need to get the fixing fast part...